# Justifying text and removing unwanted space

Tags: spacing

Using LaTeX text justification, sometimes the output tend to have more space in order to be justified from right and left as shown in the following picture. Between the Dr. and Lloyd is more space than required. How can I avoid this.

[image]

Comment: Would you consider adding your code? Otherwise, it will be just a guessing game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When LaTeX recognizes a *colon* after a small letter which is followed by a capital letter, LaTeX interprets this as the end of a sentence and thus as a *period*. In this case, the space between colon/period and the following word becomes bigger and can become ugly for justified texts. As recommended in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134856), you should tell LaTeX that this colon is not ending the sentence by typing `Dr.\ Lloyd`.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
{\justifying\scriptsize I would like to extend my gratitude to Computer Suport Group and specially Dr. Lloyd \blindtext}

{\justifying\scriptsize I would like to extend my gratitude to Computer Suport Group and specially Dr.\ Lloyd \blindtext}
\end{document}
```

It has been asked in comment, if this behaviour persists for other babel-variants of the English language. I have tested the below MWE and got the same result for all combinations I have tested so far.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
,british
,UKenglish
,USenglish
,english
,american
]{babel}

\begin{document}
\noindent Dr. Lloyd\\
Dr.\ Lloyd
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does it even if you specify you're writing American English with babel? Another solution would be to write British English if it's possible.

Comment: @Bernard I am not sure, if I got you right. Please see the second part of my answer. Until we do not get more information from the OP, I can't provide any better.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi -- good enough answer, but the problam is a *period*, not a colon.  also, this situation is built into tex itself; doesn't matter what language is involved.  (documented in *the texbook*.)

Comment: Probably `Dr.~Lloyd` is even better as it disallows a line break after `Dr.`

Comment: Another option is to issue the directive `\frenchspacing`, which instructs TeX not to insert extra whitespace after *any* punctuation marks.

Comment: @egreg absolutely. I am addressing this in my linked answer. I would even prefer `Dr.\,Lloyd` but the question was, how the extra space arises. Mico: Interesting, as I never heard about, but maybe a bit harsh... The text in the "MWE" is in English, so.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for your feedback. You are right with the period and my English is just to bad to distinguish these words... But in fact, the problem was that LaTeX sees a period, where we need a colon. I will add something to my answer.

Comment: I'd exclude `Dr.\,Lloyd` from the possibilities; a thin space *might* be used between initials (I don't like it), never between a title and the name.

Comment: @egreg Oh yes. I got confused by myself. Here it's a title and not an initial. Therefore I correct: I like `Dr.~J.\,Doe` most. But that's a typographic discussion...

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. `Dr.\ Lloyd` worked fine. I believe this has been always the problem throughout my document. After the period LaTeX assumes that the line has ended. `\frenchspacing` made it easier as you need to use it once.