# Package for typing honorific title

Tags: typography, french

There is a set of command (or a package providing it) to type words like Dr, Mr, Pr, PhD?

I search something better than doing `D\up{r}` (the abbreviation for *Doctor*, in French), for example. Especially when `\setdefaultlanguage{}` is activated.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean: surely you just type `Dr`, `Mr`, `Ph.D.` and so on (I'm assuming the UK tradition that abbreviated words where the last letter is still present _don't_ have a `.`).

Comment: What is `\up` supposed to be? Please give an example with code. If you need those very often, just write your own commands for it which you can change any time you like. E.g. `\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\Dr}{Dr~}
\newcommand*{\PhD}{Ph.D.~}
\setlength{\textwidth}{.1cm}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\Dr Joe and \PhD Smith
\end{document}`

Comment: In http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134856 I have written a bit about what spacings to use for titles.

Comment: I simply use `Dr.\ Joe`.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, `\up` put the word between {} as superscript. I apologize because I didn’t explain correctly why the *r* have to be in superscript. In some languages (like French) this abbreviation is written like this. So I was asking for a package witch do this when `\setdefaultlanguage{french}` is activated, for example.

Comment: @Sigur `Dr.~Joe` would be more appropriate with respect to line breaks, since `Dr.\ Joe` can be broken over two lines.

Comment: Do you have to use `polyglossia` or would `babel` be ok, too? Please provide an MWE as such information is important in order to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to answer your question: No, I do not know any package which does this. But well... I do not know all of them.

In any case, I would define my own custom commands which give you the flexibility to change your rules afterwards. Just imagine that your lector does not like the superscript version. With custom commands you can change that in a second.

With babel you can do:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\newcommand*{\Dr}{%
    \iflanguage{english}{Dr.~}{%
    \iflanguage{french}{D\textsuperscript{r}~}{}%
        }}

\begin{document}
Test: \Dr John Smith

\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
Test: \Dr Jean Forgeron
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why no tie for the French version?

Comment: I'd put a tie in the French version _and_ a comment sign `%` after the French line (or no new line for the two closing braces).

Comment: +1 just for the names :-)  Note that Forgeron is actually quite rare as a surname; better examples for the same profession would be Maréchal or Fabre; or the different variants of Lefèvre.

Comment: Thank you @LaRiFaRi, that’s great! I will probably complete it and make a package.

Comment: @fauve That's nice to hear. Maybe you can even add variants like uk or us English in order to have a period or not at the end. (assuming Joseph was right in his comment... I did no research but I like those locale differences a lot).

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer Thanks :-) Unluckily, my French is even worse then my Ti*k*Z, so I had to ask Google for that translation... Well, I leave it as it is. Sounds nice.